# Converting output from API to CSV

Tags: python, api, csv, screen-scraping

I am trying to use an API for a platform called "ParseHub". They have sample code to use it in Python but unfortunately I am not the best in Python and I cannot figure out how to save the file as a CSV... Here is the code:

```
import requests

params = {
  "api_key": "tSKqprcg7k-S",
  "format": "csv"
  }
r = requests.get('https://www.parsehub.com/api/v2/projects/tq1H9ha1sKAQ/last_ready_run/data', params=params)
print(r.text)
```

How can I save the output as a CSV or excel file?

Thank you!

Edit: Here is what the output looks like. It's just a ton of rows like this

```
"132","Adult","2","2018-03-22","99","38","2"
"151","Adult","2","2018-03-23","99","30","2"
"152","Adult","2","2018-03-24","99","29","2"
"138","Adult","2","2018-03-25","99","36","2"
```

Comment: Could you give the output? What does `print(r.text)` give?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the output of the query is already a valid set of CSV rows so you can probably just write it as is to a file.

```
# Your code

import requests

params = {
  "api_key": "tSKqprcg7k-S",
  "format": "csv"
  }
r = requests.get('https://www.parsehub.com/api/v2/projects/tq1H9ha1sKAQ/last_ready_run/data', params=params)
print(r.text)

# This bit of code will write the result of the query to output.csv

with open('output.csv', 'w+') as f:
    f.write(r.text)
```